# message_content not working in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I tried using the *message_content* intent, and it won't give me the content of any message I send in the server, but the bot is online and it gives me this output:

> discord.client: logging in using static token
> discord.gateway: Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: 62a3a6206e8367f9c4c60db239487b)
> Ready

Here's my code:

```py
import discord
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents(message_content=True, guilds=True))

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.content)

client.run("Token")
```

I tried to @ the bot, but nothing happens either.

Answer (score 0):

usage of Intents is different [doc](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#intents)

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.content)
client.run("xxx")
```

ps  Shard ID None has connected to Gateway is not an error, its info message that your bot is connected to server